# Spring security empty dependency bean on UserDetailsService own implementation

Tags: spring, spring-security

I develop app consiting of Spring, Wicket, Hibernate and Spring Security. Everything works OK, but now I added own implementation of UserDetailsService to fetch users from database. I configured it in applicationContext-security.xml file and added dependency to my UserDAO using Spring. However, I got null-pointer exception because of my userDAO being null. Why is this dependency not working? I do this the very same way in, for example, WebPages subclasses and everything works well.

```
@Service
public class ComicsUserDetailsService implements
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

    @SpringBean
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public ComicsUserDetailsService() {
        System.out.println("$$$ UserDetailsService created");
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        (bla bla)
    }
}
```

UserDAO is quite simple class

```
@Service
public class UserDAO {

    public UserDAO() {
        System.out.println("$$$ UserDAO created");
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

        (fetch and other bla bla methods) 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, enlightenment always come a minute too late. Simple, @SpringBean annotation is wicket-specific. Hence, in SpringSecurity is not wicket-dependent so just replacing it with @Autowired do the magic.